# Unable to su in terminal due to PIE

Tags: android, adb

Attempting reverse tether Android via USB to the PC, following the following [guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2287494).

However, not able to `su` once connected via ADB. Got the same error when attempting superuser mode from the PC terminal and also using terminal emulator on the android device.

> Error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported.

Looked it up and found that most issues raised were related to compilation of project sources addressed via `CFLAGS += -fPIE -pie` or `LDFLAGS += -fPIE -pie` .

However, how since `su` is a common shell command, I don’t think it applies.

Comment: Please shed some light on why you thought `su` was different

Comment: Sorry, I thought the basic shell commands in system\bin would be automatically allowed to run. Wasn't aware earlier that its also regulated by the PIE rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `su` binary you use is simply too old (and therefore is not compiled for PIE) and does not work with the Android version/image which is installed on your phone (which requires all executables to have PIE).

Install an newer `su` binary that fits to your Android version and the error will be gone.

Comment: This is the obvious answer. The less obvious part is why this many times covered question was not close voted as duplicate instead

Comment: Appreciate the patience. Managed to renew the supersu and now 'su' is executable